# Why is my gen_server not respecting pattern matching?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, gen-server

Hello I am trying to figure out why my implementation of `gen_server` is not respecting pattern matching:

If I run `gen_server:call(ServerRef,state)` it gets in the second pattern of `handle_call` and i do not understand why , since the the first pattern should get hit.
Is there a problem when sending `atoms`?

**Module**

```
-module(wk).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-compile(export_all).


-record(state,{
   limit,
   processed=[],
   unknown=[],
   counter=0
}).
start_link(Limit)->
   gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, Limit, []).

start(Limit)->
    gen_server:start(?MODULE,Limit,[]).
init(Limit)->
    State=#state{limit=Limit},
    {ok,State}.


handle_call(From,state,State)->
    {reply,State,State};
handle_call(From,Message,State=#state{processed=P,limit=L,counter=C})->
     Reply=if C=:=L;C>L -> exit(consumed);
              C<L       -> {{processed,self(),os:timestamp()},Message}
     end,
    {reply,Reply,State#state{counter=C+1,processed=[Message,P]}}.

handle_info(Message,State=#state{unknown=U})->
    {noreply,State#state{unknown=[Message|U]}}.
```

Calling:
`>gen_server:call(ServerRef,state)` enters into the second pattern too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have wrong parameter order: it should be [`Module:handle_call(Request, From, State)`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_call-3). So the first pattern would only match when `From` is `state`.